# Python3.7 asyncio start webserver (FastAPI) and aio_pika consumer

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, fastapi, hypercorn

In my project I try to start a REST API (built with FastAPI and run with Hypercorn), additional I want on startup also to start a RabbitMQ Consumer (with aio_pika):

Aio Pika offers a robust connection which automatically reconnects on failure. If I run the code below with `hypercorn app:app` the consumer and the rest interface starts correctly, but the reconnect from aio_pika does not work anymore. How can I archive a production stable RabbitMQ Consumer and RestAPI in two different processes (or threads?). My python version is 3.7, please note I am actually a Java and Go developer in case my approach is not the Python way :-)

```
@app.on_event("startup")
def startup():
   loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(main(loop))


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
   return {"Hello": "World"}


async def main(loop):
connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
    "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/", loop=loop
)

async with connection:
    queue_name = "test_queue"

    # Creating channel
    channel = await connection.channel()  # type: aio_pika.Channel

    # Declaring queue
    queue = await channel.declare_queue(
        queue_name,
        auto_delete=True
    )  # type: aio_pika.Queue

    async with queue.iterator() as queue_iter:
        # Cancel consuming after __aexit__
        async for message in queue_iter:
            async with message.process():
                print(message.body)

                if queue.name in message.body.decode():
                    break
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you create a new event loop in the startup function, which I think may be related. Could you say why it is required?

Comment: It is not required, I thought it was the way to do it. Similar to go

Comment: Ah, does it work without that? I'd imagine differing event loops could cause an issue.

Comment: you mean with get_current_event_loop() instead of a new one? Yes I tried it but it has the same issue.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping it would be that. Is there anything logged that could give a clue here? (Otherwise I can't see the issue).

Comment: Not at all, I tried to change the with the current_event_loop, to pass as argument for the consumer and this seems to work now`@app.on_event("startup")
def startup():
    print("jdklasjdlas")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(main(loop))`
Thanksfor your help

Comment: btw thanks for your work on Hypercorn! Awesome Job!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of @pgjones I managed changed the consuming start to:

```
@app.on_event("startup")
def startup():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(main(loop))
```

And start the `job` with `asyncio.ensure_future` and pass the current event loop as an argument, which solved the issue.

Would be interesting if somebody has a different/better approach
Thanks!